# How is the honorific informal form of verbes created?

Tags: grammar, verb, honorific, conjugation, informal

From what I understood, if I want to talk about my teacher with my friend I have to use the honorific informal form, but how do I create this form? Do I just remove 다 from the verb to then make it become 시다 that conjugated at the informal present becomes 셔. For example 가다 becomes 가셔. And when the root ends with a consonant do I use 으시다 that then becomes 으셔. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Except for some words that you have to use different words instead when putting into honorific forms.

- “먹다” →

  - “먹으셔” (from “먹다”) (incorrect)
  - “드셔” (from “들다”) (correct)
  - “잡수셔” (from “잡수다”) (correct)

Comment: Ok, as you told me I'll have to sometimes use special honorific verbs with the honorific form. Do I use these only when I'm directly referring to people with higher social status or, for example, also when I'm referring to myself while I'm speaking with them?

Comment: @EmaTavox Only when you’re referring to them. It’s never used to describe what oneself’s doing, unless you’re being sarcastic.

Comment: @EmaTavox I mean, the honorific forms. You don’t refer to yourself with honorific forms.

Comment: Thank you so much.